# how to sort array of objects by condition javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, object

I have array of objects with properties.

I would like to sort by status, that is
15, 17 then 16 at last in javascript

For a array of objects , status having value `16`

should be placed at last and rest should sort by ascending as the expected output.

How to do in javascript

```
var result = arrobj.filter(e=>e.details.status !== 16).sort(a, b) => a.status - b.status;
```

```
var arrobj = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": 'xyz',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 15
    }
  },
  { 
    "id":2,
    "name": 'abc',
    "details": {
    "job": 'partime',
    "status": 16
    }
  },
  { 
    "id":3,
    "name": 'zen',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 17
    }
  },
  { 
   "id":5,
    "name": 'abu',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 16
    }
  },
{ 
   "id":7,
    "name": 'john',
    "details": {
    "job": 'parttime',
    "status": 15
    }
  },
 { 
   "id":10,
    "name": 'jocob',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 17
    }
  }
]

Expected Output

[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": 'xyz',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 15
    }
  },
 { 
   "id":7,
    "name": 'john',
    "details": {
    "job": 'parttime',
    "status": 15
    }
  },
  { 
    "id":3,
    "name": 'zen',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 17
    }
  },
 { 
   "id":10,
    "name": 'jocob',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 17
    }
  },
  { 
    "id":2,
    "name": 'abc',
    "details": {
    "job": 'partime',
    "status": 16
    }
  },
  { 
   "id":5,
    "name": 'abu',
    "details": {
    "job": 'fulltime',
    "status": 16
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Why are you filter object with status 16 if you need it ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for reply,  I need to get array of objects with status `15,17,16` so I thought filter not equal to 16 first, then sort rest ascending and add the object with status 16 at last, but i got stuck to do

Answer (score 2):

We can customize sort rules using the `compareFn` in [`Array.prototype.sort(compareFn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description).

Example:

```js
var result = arrobj
    .sort((obja, objb) => {
        let a = obja.details.status
        let b = objb.details.status
        if (a == 16) a = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        if (b == 16) b = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        return a - b
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const results = [...arrobj.filter(ob => ob.details.status !== 16).sort((a,b) => a.details.status - b.details.status), ...arrobj.filter(ob => ob.details.status === 16)]
```

You mean this?

Answer (score 1):

for es5

```
 arrobj.sort((a, b) => {
     if (a.details.status === 16) {
         return 1;
     } else if (b.details.status === 16) {
         return -1
     } else {
         return a.details.status - b.details.status
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to add `.status` in the sort function `sort()`
To place the object with status 16 at the end, I made an seperate array with status 16 and added on the end of the array with everything else.

```
var result = arrobj.filter(e=>e.details.status !== 16).sort( (a, b) => a.details.status - b.details.status);
result = result.concat(arrobj.filter(e=>e.details.status == 16));


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

From EcmaScript 2019 Array.sort is stable. This mean that you can split that complex sorting into 2 - first by status, then placing all items with status 16 in the back. Not efficient solution

```
arrobj.sort((first,second) => first.details.status - second.details.status)
      .sort((first, second) => (first.details.status === 16) - (second.details.status === 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will also work for your use case. You were really close though

```
arrobj.filter(e=>e.details.status !== 16).sort((a, b) => {return a.details.status - b.details.status}).concat(arrobj.filter(e=>e.details.status == 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort` function is not correct. Try this one. I also add the ability to change the sort order.

```js
// Sort by status
function sortByStatus(array, asc = true) {
  let newArray = [...array];

  // filter and sort
  if (asc) {
    newArray = newArray.filter(e => e.details.status !== 16).sort((a, b) => a.details.status > b.details.status && 1 || -1);
  } else {
    newArray = newArray.filter(e => e.details.status !== 16).sort((a, b) => a.details.status < b.details.status && 1 || -1);
  }

  return newArray;
}

// merge result
const result = [...sortByStatus(arrobj), arrobj.filter(e => e.details.status === 16)];
```

```js
var arrobj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": 'xyz',
    "details": {
      "job": 'fulltime',
      "status": 15
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": 'abc',
    "details": {
      "job": 'partime',
      "status": 16
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": 'zen',
    "details": {
      "job": 'fulltime',
      "status": 17
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": 'abu',
    "details": {
      "job": 'fulltime',
      "status": 16
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": 'john',
    "details": {
      "job": 'parttime',
      "status": 15
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": 'jocob',
    "details": {
      "job": 'fulltime',
      "status": 17
    }
  }
];

// Sort by status
function sortByStatus(array, asc = true) {
  let newArray = [...array];

  // filter and sort
  if (asc) {
    newArray = newArray.filter(e => e.details.status !== 16).sort((a, b) => a.details.status > b.details.status && 1 || -1);
  } else {
    newArray = newArray.filter(e => e.details.status !== 16).sort((a, b) => a.details.status < b.details.status && 1 || -1);
  }

  return newArray;
}

// merge result
const result = [...sortByStatus(arrobj), arrobj.filter(e => e.details.status === 16)];
console.log(result);
```